# SOAP Web Service basics

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

am new on WS.
some simple questions in my mind, please try to solve it.

1. i did a demo WS for *Calculator* on calculator(), where it has one UI where i enter values for it, internally pass it to WS. Ok i got answer/output. but if i want to create only webservice which take/give xml data or just give xml data. how can i create it.
2. i found some *WS URL's* about some fame company. is it used by using by opening Connection. how they define this URL? am using MyEclipse10 when i went to create new WS, needed to use Java Bean class for create it. ok, if i create myWS url then how it ll get call? because it is JavaBean?
3. and if just want to create WS then i need not required to create *New WS client*?

i dont know it is simple or may be foolish question, when i walk on WS i stop here. i feel like , without basic knowledge started to build it.

please, clear it. 
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

MyEclipse (as well as Eclipse, IBM D Developer, etc) let you create a Java Web service server in one of two ways:

- Bottom up Java Bean: you supply a bean, it turns it into a WSDL (and generates the corresponding stub code)
- Top down WSDL: you supply a WSDL, and it generates the corresponding stub code

When a company creates a web page, they set up a web server and publish some HTML pages on it.

When a company publishes a WSDL, they *also* set up a web server ... and publish an XML WSDL on it.

The URL you go to in order to read a WSDL is just an ordinary HTTP web server, that happens to be serving an XML WSDL at that location.

The WSDL specifies *where* the service can be found, and *what* operations and data types the service uses.  A WSDL you create, or a WSDL that's published by some other company.

'Hope that helps

Comment: yes. ok, i created one Java Bean, which have some methods which fetches data from DB whatever(but jst fetching and want to show outside), i created WS for that bean class. then which url or how can i access it from another system to get that output(fetched data)? by the way it is bean class WS how it is possible?